# Drawing multiple random canvas images in a loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a grid with random images assigned to each square.  I'm having trouble with the draw sequence and potentially closure issues with the Javascript variables.  Any help is appreciated.

```
var tileSize = 30;
var drawCanvasImage = function(ctx,tile,x,y) {
return function() {
    ctx.drawImage(tile,x,y);
    console.log("x = " + x + "/ y = " + y);
}
}

function textures(ctx) {
var grass = new Image();
var sea = new Image();
var woods = new Image();
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<=20; j++) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1);
        x = i * tileSize;
        y = j * tileSize;
        if (rand == 1) {
            grass.onload = drawCanvasImage(ctx,grass,x,y);
        } else if (rand == 2) {
            sea.onload = drawCanvasImage(ctx,sea,x,y);
        } else {
            woods.onload = drawCanvasImage(ctx,woods,x,y);
        }
    }
}
grass.src = "textures/grass.png";
sea.src = "textures/sea.png";
woods.src = "textures/woods.png";
}

//function called by the onload event in the html body tag
function draw() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("grid").getContext('2d');
grid(ctx);  //a function to draw the background grid - works fine
textures(ctx);
}
```

The current result is three drawn tiles, all at the position of x = 300 (equivalent to the i loop of 10 * the tileSize of 30) and a random y position.

After following a lead and accounting for (maybe?) closure issues by creating the variable drawCanvasImage, I at least got those three tiles to draw.

----Edit----
Working Code - Revision 2:

```
function randomArray() {
for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
    terrainArray[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*4 + 1);
        if (rand == 1) {
            terrainArray[i][j] = 3;
        } else if (rand == 2) {
            terrainArray[i][j] = 2;
        } else if (rand == 3) {
            terrainArray[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            terrainArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
}

var drawTerrain = function(ctx,tile,landUseValue) {
return function() {
    for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
            if (terrainArray[i][j] == landUseValue) {
                ctx.drawImage(tile,i*tileSize,j*tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function textures(ctx) {
var grass = new Image();
var sea = new Image();
var woods = new Image();
var desert = new Image();
grass.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,grass,3);
sea.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,sea,0);
woods.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,woods,2);
desert.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,desert,1);
grass.src = "textures/grass.png";
sea.src = "textures/sea.png";
woods.src = "textures/woods.png";
desert.src = "textures/desert.png";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rewriting the `onload`s of the three images in every iteratiom. So, it will only execute the last-added `onload` f or every image.

Suggestion: run your drawing method only after the thred are loaded(and them just call `drawCanvasImage` every iteration without an `.onload=`)

Even better:store the randoms in an array, have each image independantly walk through the array on load and add copies of only *itself* wherever applicable .

### Improvement to rev 2

```
function randomArray() {
for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
    terrainArray[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*4 + 1);
        terrainArray[i][j] = 4-rand; 
        //OR: replace above two lines with terrainArray[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*4 + 1);. There's no need to have them in exactly reverse order.
    }
}
}

var drawTerrain = function(ctx,tile,landUseValue) {
return function() {
    for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
            if (terrainArray[i][j] == landUseValue) {
                ctx.drawImage(tile,i*tileSize,j*tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function textures(ctx) {
var grass = new Image();
var sea = new Image();
var woods = new Image();
var desert = new Image();
grass.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,grass,3);
sea.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,sea,0);
woods.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,woods,2);
desert.onload = drawTerrain(ctx,desert,1);
grass.src = "textures/grass.png";
sea.src = "textures/sea.png";
woods.src = "textures/woods.png";
desert.src = "textures/desert.png";
}
```

To make it even *more* flexible, you could use an array to store the images, and then use `length`. This way, if you want to add another image, all you have to do is modify the array.

```
var srcArray=["textures/grass.png","textures/sea.png","textures/woods.png","textures/desert.png"];
var imgArray=[];
var terrainArray=[];
function textures(ctx){
randomArray();
    for(var i=0;i<srcArray.length;i++){
        imgArray[i]=new Image();
        imgArray[i].src=srcArray[i];
        imgArray[i].onload=drawTerrain(ctx,i);
    }
}
function randomArray() {
for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
    terrainArray[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
        terrainArray[i][j]=Math.floor(Math.random()*srcArray.length);

    }
}
}

var drawTerrain = function(ctx,index) {
return function() {
    for (var i=0; i<=(xValue/tileSize); i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<=(yValue/tileSize); j++) {
            if (terrainArray[i][j] == index) {
                ctx.drawImage(imgArray[index],i*tileSize,j*tileSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So now, all you have to do is call `terrain(ctx)` when you want to load all the images. And, whenever you want to *add* an image to the list of images, just add it to the array up top. You won't have to dig deeper and modify the random values and whatnot.

Comment: Your suggestion worked.  I've edited my question with the working code.  Last question, what is the advantages of your "Even better" method?

Comment: @Josh the first method, correctly implemented(which you havent done :p)

Comment: is to have a counter, and trigger the vanvas voodoo only after you have loaded all the pics. If you have an exceptionally large one,  the page will not work till it loaded. The second one displays them independantly as they load.

Comment: @osh plis the second one, IMO is better practice. I _hate_ 'increment a flag and check' algorithms :p

Comment: I think I have it now.  Does the edited code seem correct?  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Josh: Yep :) I haven't checked if it works, but the logic seems perfect!

Comment: @Josh actually there's still an improvement I can make, I'll edit it in when im back on a computer

Comment: Thanks.  That seems a much better way to do it.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Two mistakes you missed - 'terrainArray[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random()* srcArray.length);' and 'ctx.drawImage(imgArray[**index**],i*tileSize,j*tileSize);'  But thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Josh oh, whoopsies. On a phone atm, feel free to edit my answer. I cant trust my keyboard to get code right.

Answer (score 1):

It's because every time you do a loop, you assign a new function to [image].onload, overwriting the previous one. That's how you end up with only three images.
This should work:

```
if (rand == 1) {
    grass.addEventlistener('load', drawCanvasImage(ctx,grass,x,y), false);
} else if (rand == 2) {
    sea.addEventlistener('load', drawCanvasImage(ctx,sea,x,y), false);
} else {
    woods.addEventlistener('load', drawCanvasImage(ctx,woods,x,y), false);
}
```

Here you just add a new listener for every loop.

Comment: That worked.  But I have no idea why.  How is this bypassing the problem I had?  Is there a better way to do this overall?

Comment: @Josh see my answer for the why.